# .htaccess - Why does this break accessing files directly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
<Directory />
        Options All -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Allow From All
</Directory>
```

I have a bunch of XML files in this directory I do not want people to be able to browse. However, if I enable this .htaccess file you can not longer access the files directly. How is this coding effecting accessing files?

Comment: This should not have any effect on .xml files in the directory. The `AllowOverride None` disables any .htaccess you may have put in. is there any RewriteRule configured elsewhere?  Are there any other `<Directory>` blocks?

Comment: What goes wrong with the XML files? 404, 403, or other?

Comment: Just that block. Here is what the browser shows: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS I'll need to dig in to the error files

Comment: This cannot cause redirects. What's in the .htaccess? mod_rewrite would be the normal culprit for too many redirects, but the AllowOverride here makes it impossible for any .htaccess to work, unless there's another <Directory> block somewhere...

Comment: Nothing at all. I deleted the .htaccess in the directory above which was a default WP file (not needed no WP installed) and now everything redirects to the home page

Comment: There could be something else more specific in the main httpd.conf or apache2.conf, applying to a default document root, because `<Directory>` applies to a file path, not to a web path  (so `/` is not the doc root unless you are in a deeply sandboxed env - it is the filesystem's true `/`) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory  In any case, if you now have stuff redirecting to the homepage, there must be some other .htaccess or Apache conf causing it to happen.

Comment: Ok I have it fixed now. Removed the Directory in the .htaccess and all is good.

Comment: That actually sounds like it would have 500 caused errors, because `<Directory>` isn't even allowed in .htaccess